# Separar valores por delimitador SQL

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual es llamada con esta sentencia:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.ControlScrap
WHERE componente='FILTROS'
AND orden='GORE-6136'
ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, necesito en el campo `unidades` obtener ambos valores para realizar un calculo de resta, todo dentro del `SELECT`, algo tipo asi:

```
SELECT orden,
       (valor2-valor1)+1 AS Total
FROM dbo.ControlScrap
WHERE componente='FILTROS'
AND orden='GORE-6136'
ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Pero no he podido ni separar ese `VARCHAR`, como podria hacer esto? Gracias.

Comment: para que version de sql server?

Comment: @gbianchi EXPRESS, pero tal como tal es 12.0.2269.0

Comment: Eso aclaralo en la pregunta, porque es muy diferente la respuesta si es una base vieja...  esto no funciona? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas de separar valores de una columna en 2. Dejo una forma eficiente de hacerlo mediante algunas funciones. Para saber que hace cada función, es necesario que consultes la documentación de SQL Server. La función que compartió A. Cedano en los comentarios de la pregunta es muy buena opción para separar cadenas con más valores, pero puede ser demasiado para este caso.

Dejo también un ejemplo de como debes de poner los datos de prueba al hacer preguntas de SQL para evitar que la gente tenga que escribirlos.

```
CREATE TABLE ControlScrap(
    id          int,
    orden       varchar(10),
    fecha       datetime,
    componente  varchar(10),
    unidades    varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO ControlScrap
VALUES
    ( 421, 'GORE-6136', '20200924', 'FILTROS', '1-21'),
    ( 431, 'GORE-6136', '20200925', 'FILTROS', '22-41'),
    ( 433, 'GORE-6136', '20200928', 'FILTROS', '42-68'),
    ( 435, 'GORE-6136', '20200929', 'FILTROS', '69-94'),
    ( 436, 'GORE-6136', '20200930', 'FILTROS', '95-124'),
    ( 437, 'GORE-6136', '20200930', 'FILTROS', '125-149');

SELECT cs.*,
       (valor2-valor1)+1 AS Total
FROM dbo.ControlScrap cs
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TRY_CAST( SUBSTRING( unidades, 0, CHARINDEX( '-', unidades)) AS int) AS valor1,
                     TRY_CAST( STUFF( unidades, 1, CHARINDEX( '-', unidades), '') AS int) AS valor2) s
WHERE componente='FILTROS'
AND orden='GORE-6136'
ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Comment: Excelente, me sirvio, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!